# Changing AndroidManifest.xml Declarations

Tags: android, android-manifest, categories, intentfilter

In my AndroidManifest.xml, I have a declaration for `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` under the `<intent-filter>` tag. However, I sometimes want to change the value to `android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE`. This would mean that I would have to change the value from the application itself. Is there a way I can modify the manifest's declarations from hard code? Or is there a more direct way to change the intent-filter parameters of a particular Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the manifest's declarations from hard code. The Android Manifest is supposed to be immutable specially since the marketplaces use it to decide what devices your app supports.

Answer (score 0):

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    filter.addCategory( android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE); 
    registerReceiver(yourBroadCastRcver, filter);
```